# Unusually long pause trying to close ADO.NET connection object: is this normal?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I am performing a simple exercise of opening an SQL Server database connection, pulling the first record of a table from a DataReader object, and then closing the object.  However, I have noticed that theres bit of a delay, about 5 seconds or so, in closing the connection.  However, the delay only occurs after the command object executes the specified query.  I've worked in a setup like this before and don't remember there being such a long delay while closing the connection.

```
   Public Sub TestDb()
    Dim cnStrBuilder As New SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    Dim cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim sqlSelectName As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim drName As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Dim newName As New SymName
    Dim i As Integer

    cnStrBuilder.UserID = "sa"
    cnStrBuilder.ConnectTimeout = 30
    cnStrBuilder.Password = ""
    cnStrBuilder.PersistSecurityInfo = True
    cnStrBuilder.DataSource = "EMARKET\FL_DB"
    cnStrBuilder.InitialCatalog = "EmailMarketing"

    sqlSelectName.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    sqlSelectName.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [NAME]"

    System.Console.WriteLine(cnStrBuilder.ConnectionString)

    cn.ConnectionString = cnStrBuilder.ConnectionString

    Try
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cn.Open()
        End If
        System.Console.WriteLine("Connection success")

        sqlSelectName.Connection = cn

        System.Console.WriteLine("Execute Reader")
        drName = sqlSelectName.ExecuteReader

        If drName.HasRows = True Then
            System.Console.WriteLine("Read Row")
            drName.Read()

            For i = 0 To drName.FieldCount - 1
                Console.WriteLine(drName.Item(i).ToString)
            Next
        End If

        System.Console.WriteLine("Closing connection")

        sqlSelectName.Connection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Console.WriteLine("Something Happened")
        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try

System.Console.WriteLine("Done.")

End Sub
```

If I omit the lines

```
'System.Console.WriteLine("Execute Reader")
'drName = sqlSelectName.ExecuteReader
'
'If drName.HasRows = True Then
'    System.Console.WriteLine("Read Row")
'    drName.Read()
'
'    For i = 0 To drName.FieldCount - 1
'        Console.WriteLine(drName.Item(i).ToString)
'    Next
'End If
```

The connection closes almost imediately.  What gives?  I have narrowed it down to the where the `.ExecuteReader` line that causes the delay in the connection close.  **Whats causing the delay and how do I resolve it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling SQL Server to retrieve the entire table.  Yet after the first row, you stop, and close the connection.  Like you, I would expect the connection to close immediately, but perhaps the server is busy spooling the table to a place where it can return your data quickly.

Does the connection still close slowly if you only ask the server for one row?   F.e.

```
 sqlSelectName.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [NAME]"
```

Comment: Excellent thought.  It is relatively big table.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should be wrapping any objects that implement IDisposable in using statements which includes the connection object. I would try implementing something like the following which is from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f.aspx#Y400

```
Public Sub CreateCommand(ByVal queryString As String, _
  ByVal connectionString As String)
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = _
            command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        While reader.Read()
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader(0))
        End While
    End Using
End Sub
```